# Bluetooth headsets briefly connect to iPhone but then get disconnected

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

Two *BH-M20/BH-M20C* headsets are able to briefly connect to my *iPhone 6* via  Bluetooth.  I can see the connection in the *Settings | Bluetooth | My Devices*.

However they both get disconnected within 10 seconds.   These headsets both work fine when connected to my MacBook.

Why are they getting disconnected and what might be the way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You might have an issue with your iPhone.  Do you have other BT headsets that work with it?

Comment: @Allan  A headset connected by mini jack works. I don't have other bluetooths to try out presently.

Comment: Mini Jack (3.5mm) is not Bluetooth.  Since you don't have any actual diagnostic tools, you have to do this by process of elimination.  So, there are two possibilities - the BT chip/software in your phone is has a problem or that particular device is not compatible.  If you can pair a different device (headset, your iPhone to your Mac, your car, anything) and depending on the connection state, you would have narrowed it down.  At this point, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: Yes I had not intended that mini jack were a blue-tooth which is a wireless connection.  I'll have to buy another headset i guess.

Comment: Before spending money, try to find another device to connect to your iPhone.  I think you can connect a BT keyboard to an iPhone 6 running iOS 12 but you should be able to connect that phone to your Mac.  If you have a friend with BT accessories, ask to use them to test or connect to their computer - it's just for testing to see if there's an issue with your BT stack on the phone.